# How to get last record

Tags: sqlalchemy

I need to get last record from db. I'm using sqlalchemy.
At the moment, I'm doing like that:

```
obj = ObjectRes.query.all()
return str(obj[-1].id)
```

But it's too heavy query. How can I get last record better?

Comment: "Last" could have done with a clear definition here.  In a system with concurrent updates the most recently allocated id and the most recently committed id may not be the same, for example transaction A allocates id 42, transaction B allocates id 43, transaction B commits, then transaction A commits.  Which is "last"?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Take a look at [`Query.first()`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first). If you specify a [sort](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.order_by) on the right column, the first will be your last. An example could look like this:

```
obj = session.query(ObjectRes).order_by(ObjectRes.id.desc()).first()
```

Comment: @dimazubrik I get a warning using by using it `SAWarning: Can't resolve label reference '-id'; converting to text() (this warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)`

Comment: ^ This has now become an error; I used `Model.query.order_by(-Model.field_name).first()` to retrieve the desired object

Comment: Does this actually return all values of the query and then just pop the first one (ie. super inefficient) or is it smart enough to actually to something like `ORDER BY desc LIMIT 1` under the hood?

Comment: @AdamHughes you could specify this with a .limit() modifier such as session.query(ObjectRes).order_by(ObjectRes.id.desc()).limit(1)

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes it is difficult to reformulate simple things:

```
SELECT * FROM ObjectRes WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ObjectRes)
```

but this worked for me:

```
session.query(ObjectRes).filter(ObjectRes.id == session.query(func.max(ObjectRes.id)))
```

Answer (score 4):

**Don't forget to disable existing ordering if needed**

In my case I have dynamic ordered relationships:

```
class Match:
  ...
  records = relationship("Record", backref="match", lazy="dynamic", order_by="Record.id")
```

And when I tried accepted answer I got first record, not the last, cause `ORDER BY` were applied twice and spoiled the results.

According to [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.order_by):

> All existing ORDER BY settings can be suppressed by passing None

So the solution will be:

```
match = db_session.query(Match).first()
last_record = match.records.order_by(None).order_by(Record.id.desc()).first()
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer modifies the others to allow for cases where you don't know what the primary key is called.

```py
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
# ...
def last_row(Table: type, *, session): # -> Table
    primary_key = inspect(Table).primary_key[0].name # must be an arithmetic type
    primary_key_row = getattr(Table, primary_key)
    # get first, sorted by negative ID (primary key)
    return session.query(Table).order_by(-primary_key_row).first()
```