# How to query specific SQL using Flask/SQLAlchemy for Google Charts API

Tags: sql, flask, google-api, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am saving datetime and temperature values into a database and I am trying to get the last temperature and datetime value.

I tried using the code described in the link below:

[How to get last record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551952/how-to-get-last-record)

And wrote this:

```
    query1 = db.session.query.order_by(temperaturelog.dTime.desc()).first()
    query2 = db.session.query.order_by(temperaturelog.Temperature.desc()).first()
    data.append(query1)
    data.append(query2)
    return data
```

However, I got errors such as:

```
NameError: name 'session' is not defined
```

Do I need to replace 'session' with something else? I tried using the variable used in the creation of the SQLAlchemy(app) and tried replacing it with my class name for the database which is temperaturelog.

All help appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the full traceback you receive. This will help to pinpoint the exact line of code causing the error. From the snippet you've provided, there doesn't seem to be anything that would cause the NameError so it must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it's *impossible* to see where your `NameError` is coming from. In your example, you call session as an attribute of an object called `db`. If `session` doesn't exist in this context, it would throw an `AttributeError`, not `NameError`. The `NameError` is most likely coming from calling `session` in your module somewhere in an unqualified manner, before it has been defined.

Second is that your queries are different to the ones in the linked question in that you are not querying any object.

In Flask-SQLAlchemy, you can query on an object that is attached to a session upon the model itself. For example, if I have a class called `Temperature` and it is a Flask-SQLAlchemy instrumented object, you can query the class directly, e.g. `Temperature.query.all()`. The table that needs to be queried can then be inferred from the `Temperature` object's `__tablename__` attribute.

In your example you appear to be querying on the session, which is fine but `session.query` isn't specific to any model. In this case you need to call `session.query` and pass it the model that represents the table that you want it to get the data from, e.g. `session.query(Temperature).all()` is a valid query.