# how to get second-last record from a session query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8551979/4288043) tells you how to get the last row from a session query:

```
obj = session.query(ObjectRes).order_by(ObjectRes.id.desc()).first()
```

I need the one before it - how do you get the second last one?

Comment: get all (or with `LIMIT 2`) and use `obj[1]`. Or use `OFFSET 1` in SQL query

Comment: Will this work? obj = session.query(ObjectRes).order_by(ObjectRes.id.desc())[-2]

Comment: @Amit no, that thing is not a list, it's a `<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery'>`

Comment: you should already use Google to check `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in sqlalchemy

Comment: if you use `first()` to get last row then using `[-2]` you would get `second-first`, not `second-last`. You would have to change `order_by` to get it in different order and then use `.fetchall()[-2]`. Or keep order_by and use `[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
obj = session.query(ObjectRes).order_by(ObjectRes.id.desc()).offset(1).first()
```